# Limiting current for high amp motors

Tags: motor, current-limiting

What will happen if motor requirement due to more load is high(lets say 5A) and we limit current with current limiting circuit to lets say 2A. what will happen.. will it work without anything getting damaged?If not what should i do? Thanks..

Comment: It will get stuck drawing the maximum allowed current, heating up until burned, if the heat is not dissipated properly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for the answer what would you suggest as remedy.cause my motor drivers cant handle current more than 2A n mistakenly bought johnson motors.cant return thos motors and dont know cheep solution for driver circuit.Thanks.

Comment: Get the right motor drivers. Or gear the motors down so the torque load on them doesn't require more than 2A. So if you are gearing them 10:1 now and you need 5A, gear them down 25:1.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks for reply please suggest me motor driver IC cause all i found were circuit boards and no IC mentioned.

Comment: @RAJ - 5 amps is probably beyond any IC driver. That is why you're only seeing boards. In other words, you can't do it with just an IC.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are DC motors with commutators, current is proportional to torque and voltage is proportional to speed. The current limit circuit actually limits the voltage to whatever voltage is required for the current not to exceed the set limit. Depending on the type of load, that may allow the motor to operate at a speed where the load can be turned with the torque available with the set current. If the torque at 2 amps is not enough to turn the motor at all or the motor turns at a very low speed, the motor may overheat because it is not producing enough air flow in and through the motor.

If the gear ratio is changed, the motor has a better chance of producing enough torque to turn the load, but at a lower speed. There is a more torque lost in the gear when using a high ratio, but gearing to a lower speed may still be successful.

If you are driving the motor with just an IC, you may need a board. Since we don't know the voltage or anything about your control circuit, we can not suggest a driver. However the guidelines for this site say that we do not suggest specific products. We are here to answer questions about design and theory, not to help with shopping.